# Find previous byte that isn't equal to unwanted byte in Python

Tags: python, binary, blob, padding, seek

I'm programming a small script that is meant to open a binary file, find an often-changing binary blob, and copy just that blob to a new file.

Here's the layout of the binary file:

```
-JUNK (Unknown Size) (Unknown Contents)
-3-byte HEADER containing encoded size of blob
-PADDING (Unknown Size) (Every byte is FF in hex)
-Start of blob (72 bytes) (Unknown Contents)
-16 bytes that are ALWAYS the same
-End of blob (Size can be determined from subtracting (72+16) from value HEADER) (Unknown Contents)
-JUNK (Unknown Size) (Unknown Contents)
```

Here's the code I've written so far:

```
from sys import argv
import binascii
import base64

InputFileName = argv[1]

with open(InputFileName, 'rb') as InputFile:

    Constant16 = base64.b64decode("GIhTSuBask6y60iLI2VwIg==")
    Constant16Offset = InputFile.read().find(Constant16)

    InputFile.seek(Constant16Offset)
    InputFile.seek(-72,1)

    InputFile.seek(-1,1)
    FFTestVar = InputFile.read(1)

    while FFTestVar == b'\xFF':
        InputFile.seek(-2,1)
        FFTestVar = InputFile.read(1)

    InputFile.seek(-3,1)
    BlobSizeBin = InputFile.read(3)
    BlobSizeHex = binascii.b2a_hex(BlobSizeBin)
    BlobSizeDec = int(BlobSizeHex, 16)

    InputFile.seek(Constant16Offset)
    InputFile.seek(-72,1)

    Blob = InputFile.read(BlobSizeDec)

    with open('output.bin', 'wb') as OutputFile:

        OutputFile.write(Blob)
```

Unfortunately, the *while* loop is SLOW. InputFile could be up to 24MB large, and the padding could be a huge chunk of that. Going through it one byte at a time is ridiculously slow.

I'm thinking that there's probably a better way of doing this, but an hour or two of Googling hasn't been helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: @tjameson Of the file or of my so-far horrible implementation?

Comment: Implementation. Sometimes it's easy to see the problem when it's in code.

Comment: @tjameson I added my implementation to my post.

Comment: I would use mmap module together with re module. mmap will allow to find in file (with re) anything you want and it's fast and without memory overrun. You easy adapt your code to mmap.

Comment: Hmm, if you  can afford `InputFile.read()` in the beginning, can you just scan the whole thing in memory?

Comment: @9000 Would that significantly improve my speed? How would I replicate my "seek" and "find" functions if I did that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read whole file into memory (you actually do it):

```
data = InputFile.read()
```

And then you can treat `data` like casual string (but it's not unicode string but an array of bytes, which is unfortunately called `str` under python 2.X). You need to remember offset so we will create `offset` attribute. Every line which looks like `InputFile.seek(xx)` must be translated into `offset = xx` and `InputFile.seek(xx, 1)` into `offset += xx`.

```
magic_number = base64.b64decode("GIhTSuBask6y60iLI2VwIg==")
offset = magic_number_offset = data.find(magic_number)
offset -= 72
```

Then, instead of while loop use `re` module (you need to import that module):

```
pattern = re.compile("[^\xFF]\xFF*$")
offset = pattern.search(data, endpos=offset).start() + 1
```

And the rest of code is:

```
offset -= 3
blob_size_bin = data[offset:offset+3]
blob_size_hex = binascii.b2a_hex(blob_size_bin)
blob_size_dec = int(blob_size_hex, 16)
offset = magic_number_offset - 72
blob = data[offset:offset+blob_size_dec]
```

If the files are really big and the python process consumes a lot of memory, you can use `mmap` module instead of loading whole file into memory.

If this solutions is still slow, you can reverse order of your data (`reversed_data = data[::-1]`) and search for pattern `[^\ff]`.

Comment: I just woke up, this looks great! I'll test it in a little bit. One quick question, though: Won't your _pattern.search()_ implementation find any matches that are in the first JUNK section of an input file and return that before it finds the beginning of the PADDING section?

Comment: No. Notice the dollar sign `$` character at the end of the pattern. It means that the match must ends at position determined by `endpos` argument (or if the `endpos` was omitted then the match must ends where the whole string ends).